# Rails ActiveRecord join table with array of ids without n+1 request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I need to retrieve records from an array of Ids like:
`User.where(id: [1,1,2])`
BUT the problem is that I only get two records from this request and I want to have the [#User id:1] in double as number 1 appears twice in the array.
I could do a n+1 request but that's not very optimistic...

Comment: So the way this query is written, you will only get each unique user once. However, once this query is executed, rails caches this result and referring to `User` with id=1 will not run an extra query (it depends how you write the query and how you use the result, but that is possible and how rails in general solves the N+1 problem). Explain in little more detail _why_ you need it this way, e.g. lookup users for something ... and then we can help show you maybe the _rails way_ ?

Answer (score 0):

The steps you should follow if you want a single simple query to database:

- Create a hash based on the array like:

  `hash = {1=>2, 2=>1, 3=>1, 4=>3} for [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4]`
- Query simply:

  `users = User.where(id: your_array.uniq)`

  # Your case

  `users = User.where(id: [1, 1, 2].uniq)     # because [1, 1, 2].uniq => [1, 2]`
- make your array:

```
  the_way_i_want = []
  hash.each do |key, value|
    value.times do
      the_way_i_want.push users.where(id: key)
    end

  end
```

- set the users = the_way_i_want and return

```
 users =  the_way_i_want
```

crude but will save database access :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about creating 1 request to DB, and then just format your data

```
user_ids = [1, 1, 2] # this you have
```

- Create a hash `{ user_id: user_record, .... }`

  `users = User.where(id: user_ids).map { |u| [u.id, u]}.to_h`
- Then create an array with all the records you want

  ```
  user_ids.map do |u_id|
    users[u_id]
  end
  ```